# Grails Quartz MongoDB connections keep opening

Tags: mongodb, grails, quartz-scheduler

I have a grails app that uses quartz to loop through a domain class every 20 seconds.

Every time the quartz job is executed, another connection is made to Mongo. The previous ones do not close for some reason and so after 11 connections the job stops working (connection timeout). 
I tried another approach by calling a URL with the service methods being called in the action, but the number of connections still keep rising. When I call the URL repeatedly without the Quartz job running, only 4 new connections are made and no more.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Grails 2.1.2, MongoDB plugin 1.1.0, Quartz 1.0

Comment: Hey @martin can you please share your mongoDb connection setting with quartz

Answer (score 3):

For me it works with the following workaround: wrap your execution code in a `[SomeDomain].withNewSession { }` call.

Example with `User` domain

```
def execute() {
   User.withNewSession {
      //your code
   }
}
```